# The initialization part is not called

Tags: delphi, linker, initialization, c++builder, virtualtreeview

I'm maintaining the VirtualTreeView component for Delphi and C++Builder. With Delphi everything is okay but when I compile the packages with the C++Builder the code in the initialization part in the Delphi units is not called. Any ideas?

Comment: I for one cannot understand the question. It's lacking in detail.  Could you show maybe some small repro code to demonstrate your point.

Comment: Are you expecting Delphi code to be compiled/executed when building under C++ Builder? Those are two different languages...

Comment: @Jerry: I can't speak for Roman, but I certainly expect Delphi code to be compiled and executed when used in C++Builder. What do you think the VCL is? And it is a bit disconcerting that init or finit code is not called from C++Builder.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I could be wrong, as I've never used C++ Builder, but I would expect a C++ project to be all C++ code. It's my understanding the VCL is replicated in C++ code, never imagined C++ and Delphi combined in the same compilation.

Comment: @Jerry, C++ Builder can consume Delphi-compiled DCUs and BPLs. The VCL is not replicated in multiple languages.

Comment: @Jerry:C++ Builder uses Delphi code for all of the VCL components. It contains its own Delphi compiler. Every VCL component on the Delphi palette is also available to C++ Builder. So yes, C++ Builder executes Delphi code.

Comment: Yes, you obviously never used C++Builder. It uses the **Delphi** VCL or FMX and parts of the VCL and other Delphi code. Uncompiled code is compiled by the **Delphi** compiler into object files (and headers), and these are linked together with the C++ units, in C++Builder.  So yes, they are compiled and executed and used by C++.

Comment: @Jerry: what is "replicated" is merely the interface section of a Delphi unit. It is compiled (by the **Delphi** compiler) into a C++ header.

Comment: C++ Builder does not execute Delphi code. It compiles Delphi code and then links it.

Comment: The resulting program does execute Delphi code, though.

Comment: @RomanKassebaum Possibly of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114996/implementing-virtualtreeview-tvtdefaultaccessibleprovider-in-c-builder

Answer (score 10):

When a Delphi unit's `initialization`/`finalization` sections are not being called in a C++Builder project, it usually means the Delphi unit is not being linked into the final executable, typically because the C++ code is not directly referencing any code in the unit, so it gets optimized out.  C++Builder is a bit more aggressive about removing unused code than Delphi is.  In Delphi, simply adding a unit to a `uses` clause forces that unit to be linked to.  That is not the case in C++.  `#include`ing a Delphi unit's `.hpp` file in C++ code is not enough to guarantee the unit is linked to, if the C++ code does not use anything from the `.hpp` file.

Indy ran into this problem in several of its units, most notably `IdAllAuthentications`, `IdAllFTPListParsers`, and `IdAllHeaderCoders`.  These units all contain only initialization/finalization code, no interface code, so their generated `.hpp` files were basically empty. To force linkage, I had to add `{$HPPEMIT}` statements to the `interface` section to output `#pragma link` statements in the generated `.hpp` files.  For example:

```pascal
unit IdAllAuthentications;

interface

{
Note that this unit is simply for listing ALL Authentications in Indy.
The user could then add this unit to a uses clause in their program and
have all Authentications linked into their program.

ABSOLUTELY NO CODE is permitted in this unit.

}

{$I IdCompilerDefines.inc}

// RLebeau 2/14/09: this forces C++Builder to link to this unit so
// the units can register themselves correctly at program startup...

{$IFDEF HAS_DIRECTIVE_HPPEMIT_LINKUNIT}
  {$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}
{$ELSE}
  {$HPPEMIT '#pragma link "IdAllAuthentications"'}
{$ENDIF}

implementation

// uses units that self-register in their initialization sections ...

end.
```

[`{$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HPP_emit_(Delphi)#For_C.2B.2B_on_Mobile_Platforms.2C_.7B.24HPPEMIT_LINKUNIT.7D_Replaces_.23pragma_link) was introduced in XE5 Update 2, to help with linking units that use unit-scope names:

> New: You can now use HPPEMIT Delphi compiler directives for linking and generating C++ namespace declarations.
>
> ...
>
> **{$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}** replaces #pragma link for the iOS device target platform.
>   For more information, see HPPEMIT.

> For C++ applications, `{$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}` replaces `#pragma link` on mobile platforms.
>
> The Delphi run time has units that must be linked in order to enable some functionality. In C++, auto-linking was previously achieved using the following directive:
>
> `{$HPPEMIT '#pragma link "<unitname>"'}`
>
> Now you should use the following directive instead:
>
> `{$HPPEMIT LINKUNIT}`

`LINKUNIT` generates a `#pragma link` statement that references the calling unit using the correct decorated/namespaced unit name.

Comment: I added to the VirtualTreesCR.cpp file the following line:
#pragma link "VirtualTrees"

And to the VirtualTrees.pas
  {$HPPEMIT '#pragma link "VirtualTrees"'}

But the designtime package itself already has the problem. I simply drop the VirtualTree on a form and I get an AV because some variables are not assigned.

Comment: @Remy: We can set breakpoints in the methods and constructors of those units, so I guess the unit was linked in. Interestingly we cannot set a breakpoint in the code of the initialization section of the VirtualTrees unit. So either this is not supported in C++ Builder, or the initialization section of the unit was not linked, but the rest of the unit was.