# Implementing VirtualTreeView TVTDefaultAccessibleProvider in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, accessibility, c++builder, virtualtreeview

When using VirtualStringTree to add accessibility support it is required to include the unit `VirtualTrees.Accessibility` in the `uses` section. This works in Delphi.

The equivalent of this in C++ Builder would be to include the `#include "VirtualTrees.Accessibility.hpp"`. But including the include file doesn't have any effect.

I've traced the problem to the `VirtualTrees.Accessibility.pas` file and it executes a few lines of code to register the default accessibility provider in Delphi while this code is absent from the hpp file. So including the hpp does include the class but not the code which registers the provider.

The code in question (at the end of `VirtualTrees.Accessibility.pas` is this):

```pascal
var
  DefaultAccessibleProvider: TVTDefaultAccessibleProvider;
  DefaultAccessibleItemProvider: TVTDefaultAccessibleItemProvider;
  MultiColumnAccessibleProvider: TVTMultiColumnAccessibleItemProvider;

initialization
  if DefaultAccessibleProvider = nil then
  begin
    DefaultAccessibleProvider := TVTDefaultAccessibleProvider.Create;
    GetAccessibilityFactory.RegisterAccessibleProvider(DefaultAccessibleProvider);
  end;
  if DefaultAccessibleItemProvider = nil then
  begin
    DefaultAccessibleItemProvider := TVTDefaultAccessibleItemProvider.Create;
    GetAccessibilityFactory.RegisterAccessibleProvider(DefaultAccessibleItemProvider);
  end;
  if MultiColumnAccessibleProvider = nil then
  begin
    MultiColumnAccessibleProvider := TVTMultiColumnAccessibleItemProvider.Create;
    GetAccessibilityFactory.RegisterAccessibleProvider(MultiColumnAccessibleProvider);
  end;
finalization
  GetAccessibilityFactory.UnRegisterAccessibleProvider(MultiColumnAccessibleProvider);
  MultiColumnAccessibleProvider := nil;
  GetAccessibilityFactory.UnRegisterAccessibleProvider(DefaultAccessibleItemProvider);
  DefaultAccessibleItemProvider := nil;
  GetAccessibilityFactory.UnRegisterAccessibleProvider(DefaultAccessibleProvider);
  DefaultAccessibleProvider := nil;

end.
```

My question - how do I translate or use the above so I can have accessibility support from C++ Builder as well after including the `VirtualTrees.Accessibility.hpp` file? A translation of the above into C++ would be very appreciated.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/issues/951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on research from this link and answer by Remy Lebeau:

[The initialization part is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738153/the-initialization-part-is-not-called)

And the opened issue on VirtualTree GitHub:

https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/issues/951

I am sharing a solution here, how this might be achieved by either one of the following:

**Method A**

By calling:

`TVirtualTreeAccessibility::RegisterDefaultAccessibleProviders();`

somewhere in the cpp file, as suggested by Joachim Marder

**Method B**

By adding:

`#pragma link "VirtualTrees.Accessibility"`

in the cpp source file

**Method C**

By adding something like:

`{$HPPEMIT '#pragma link "VirtualTrees.Accessibility"'}`

in the `VirtualTrees.Accessibility.pas` source code